# spark dataframe sorted map column save to hive back to random status

Tags: scala, dictionary, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark and I am trying to use the udf sort the map type column in spark dataframe, after that i try to save the data to hive , the code as follows :

```
val vectorHead = udf { (z: SparseVector, x: SparseVector, y: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) =>

  var map2 = Map.empty[String, Double]

  for (i <- x.values.indices) {
    if (x.values(i) * z.values(i) >= threshold && y(i)!="") {
      map2+=(y(i)->x.values(i)* z.values(i))
    }
  }

  ListMap(map2.toSeq.sortBy(-_._2):_*)

}

val rescaledDataNew = dataFrame.withColumn("words_with_tf*idf", vectorHead(dataFrame("TFFeatures"), dataFrame("IDFFeatures"), dataFrame("new_words"))).drop("words","TFFeatures","IDFFeatures")

println("This is the new data after drop low TF*IDF")
rescaledDataNew.show()
rescaledDataNew.createTempView("TEST")
rescaledDataNew.sqlContext.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + dataSavePath)
rescaledDataNew.sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE " + dataSavePath + " AS SELECT * FROM TEST")
```

After running, i got no error no warns and the result is :

```
{"美食":6.978342,"游艇":8.91278,"翠园":6.1228666,"花桥镇":10.032949,"青咖喱鸡":6.914152}
```

what i want is :

```
{"花桥镇":10.032949,"游艇":8.91278,"美食":6.978342,"青咖喱鸡":6.914152,"翠园":6.1228666}
```

when change the code to

```
ListMap(map2.toSeq.sortBy(-_._2):_*).toString
```

then the result is:

```
Map{"花桥镇"->10.032949,"游艇"->8.91278,"美食"->6.978342,"青咖喱鸡"->6.914152,"翠园"->6.1228666}
```

So, can any one tell me what should i do to get what i want ?

Comment: what i am use are:     import scala.collection.immutable.{ListMap,Map}

Comment: I don't understand your question. Doesn't `ListMap(map2.toSeq.sortBy(-_._2):_*)` already solve your question?

Comment: no, it doesn't works when use the df.show( ),it's still random

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with show() method. Try writing df to a file, it should be sorted as you want it.